# Run other code while timer is running in c#

Tags: c#, timer, console

I am making a C# console maths test where the user answers maths questions

I am trying to add a timer to the test, but I can't make my timer run at the same time as my other code

Here is an example of my code:

```
class Program
{
    public static OtherCode()
    {
        \\*other code for test
    }
    public class Timer
    {
        public static int Timers(int timeLeft)
        {
            do
            {
                Console.Write("\rtimeLeft: {0} ", timeLeft);
                timeLeft--;
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            } while (timeLeft > 0);
            Console.Write(Environment.NewLine);
            return timeLeft;
        }
    }
    
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int numberOfSeconds = 30;
        Timer.Timers(numberOfSeconds);

        \\other code
        OtherCode();
    }
}
```

I would like my timer to be running at the top of the console and the maths questions to be asked underneath like this except the question should be on a newline:
[image]

Any help appreciated!

**UPDATE**

When I add Console.SetCursorPosition() to my code like so:

```
do
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 9);        
        Console.Write("\rtimeLeft: {0} ", timeLeft);
        timeLeft--;
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    } while (timeLeft > 0);
```

My code won't move the timer but when I type the answer to one of my maths questions it makes me type it on the same line as the timer like this:
[image]

Comment: create a task: ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: The problem is that the `Console.ReadLine()` is blocking, so you can't execute other code. You could create the timer on another thread.

Comment: don't see any. but the `Thread.Sleep` is blocking. this is all simply sequential, not parallel, as it is currently written.

Comment: What about a [System.Timers.Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netframework-4.8) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have a status message that stays at the bottom of the console you need a way to manipulate the screen buffer so you continuously overwrite your status message.

The `Console.SetCursorPos` can be used for this and is usefull in more advanced scenarios, but I think you can get by with simply using \r to reset the cursor to the beginning of the line.

Proof of consept:

```
using System;

namespace consoletimer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            int numberOfSeconds = 300;
            var thread = new System.Threading.Thread(()=> PrintStatusMessage(numberOfSeconds));
            thread.Start();
            int n = 5;
            while(n-- > 0){
                WriteToScreen("Example text", false);
                ReadInput();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            }
        }

        static void PrintStatusMessage(int numberOfSeconds){
            var whenToStop = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(numberOfSeconds);
            while(DateTime.Now < whenToStop){
                var timeLeft = (whenToStop-DateTime.Now).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
                WriteToScreen($"Time Remaining: {timeLeft}", true);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        }

        static string ReadInput(){
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write(new string(' ',100));
            Console.CursorLeft = 0;
            return input;
        }

        static object lockObject = new object();

        static void WriteToScreen(string message, bool resetCursor){
            lock(lockObject){
                if(resetCursor){
                    int leftPos = Console.CursorLeft;
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.Write(message.PadRight( 50, ' '));
                    Console.CursorTop--;
                    Console.CursorLeft = leftPos;
                }
                else{
                    Console.WriteLine(message);
                    Console.Write(new string(' ',100));
                    Console.CursorLeft = 0;
                }   
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

***Edit***

We need to clear the next line whenever we write to the console so that we remove the status message that was there previously.

Comment: My code still looks messy because it is making me type the answers to the maths questions on the same line as the timer

Comment: Hmm, you would either need to move the cursor up one line before printing the status message and then move back to the right position on the input line, or print two blank lines before taking input and move back one line after printing the status message, but you still would need to capture the current cursor position.

Comment: @danyal51, I've updated my answer so we clear the next line when we write normal messages. That way we erase the status message so it won't interfere with the other stuff we print.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use your code with my maths project. When I run your code it still creates a new timer when you put an input

Comment: For this to work you need to replace any call to Console.WriteLine with PrintStatusMessage instead, and anytime you want to take user input you need to call ReadInput.

Comment: Now there is so much white space between each word that is printed

Answer (score 1):

You can start the Timers method within a second Thread.

To do so you need to use `System.Threading` Namespace.
Take a look at:
[Start Parameterized Thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/standard/threading/creating-threads-and-passing-data-at-start-time)

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use threads this way

```
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void OtherCode()
        {
            Console.ReadKey();
            //other code for test
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Job));
            thread.Start();

            //other code
            OtherCode();
        }

        public static void Job()
        {
            int numberOfSeconds = 30;
            Timer.Timers(numberOfSeconds);
        }
    }

    class Timer
    {
        public static int Timers(int timeLeft)
        {
            do
            {
                Console.Write("\rtimeLeft: {0} ", timeLeft);
                timeLeft--;
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            } while (timeLeft > 0);
            Console.Write(Environment.NewLine);
            return timeLeft;
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => {
            int numberOfSeconds = 30;
            Timer.Timers(numberOfSeconds);
        }));
        thread.Start();

        //other code
        OtherCode();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, @Muhammed  But when I run my code and the user types the answer to a maths question the code becomes a mess

Comment: I think it's a poor idea to just spin up a thread with no way to respond to events on the main thread. What if the user is pretty good and averages 10s per answer? You'll end up with multiple threads writing garbage to the console untill each timer runs out.

Comment: @JonC There will only be 1 timer for the whole test

Comment: @danyal51 Okay, my bad. But my first point stands. If you run a thread that prints to the console at the same time as the main thread does, you're going to end up with a pretty messy screen buffer. If we ignore threads and timers, can you update your question with what messages do you want to appear on the screen en WHEN do you want them to appear?

Comment: I am making an update that will solve your problem as soon as possible.